# How to acces/recover s a locked lost+found folder on an sd cars on the steam deck?

Tags: kde, steam

I am really sorry to post here, but neither in Steam discussions, nor on reddit I can get any help. I know some of you probably really know their stuff around linux inside the steam deck. The steam deck uses KDE and Discover.

**I have the following problem:** 
I just booted my SD up today and my SD card only shows 2.9 gb and its kinda broken and cannot access the data.

I used a `e2fsck` command I found on reddit and now I can at least access the sd card from desktop mode again. I assume all data landed in the lost+found folder is now existent on the sd card (there is nothing more, but still the sd card is almost full).

Can someone maybe explain, **how I can access the data in this lost+found folder on my sd card?** Can the sd card possibly be recovered to its former state? It has a lock symbol and I can see nothing, once i navigate into it. I just need to copy anything out of this. I dont want to wipe everything since I know the data is still recoverable. I just have no knowledge of Konsole commands...
I am a bit desperate, I would greatly appreciate any help please!!

Comment: You need root (that's the *nix superuser) access to read this directory. Depending on your setup this can be achieved using su, sudo pkexec or whatever else. You probably need a command line interface.